# Struts2 Collection Validation

Tags: java, validation, collections, struts2

Is there anyway to validate a collection of objects in a myAction-validation.xml file?

I have some JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="messageTypes" status="status">
<tr>
   <td> <s:property value="messageType" /> </td>
   <td> <s:checkbox name="messageTypes[%{#status.index}].enabled" value="enabled" label="" /> </td>
   <td> <s:textfield name="messageTypes[%{#status.index}].reminderDate" value="%{reminderDate}" label="" labelSeparator="" /> </td>
   <td> 
       <s:select name="messageTypes[%{#status.index}].reminderHour" list="hours" label="Hour"  /> 
       <s:select name="messageTypes[%{#status.index}].reminderMinute" list="minutes" label="Minute" /> </td> 
   <td> <s:textfield name="messageTypes[%{#status.index}].reminderTo"                           value="%{reminderTo}" label="" labelSeparator="" /> </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

And would like to validate the individual fields, like `reminderDate` with date validation for example. Is this possible? Note, all of the fields are Strings apart from enabled which is a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to either apply validation on your MessageType class itself using [the visitor field validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/using-visitor-field-validator.html) (see also: [visitor validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/visitor-validator.html)).  Alternately you could do the validation by overriding `validate()` in your Action (so long as you extend `ActionSupport`) and manually invoking `addActionError` or `addFieldError`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it's a shame there aren't any examples of how the visitor validator can be applied to collections?